# Woocommerce - How can I change where something shows on the checkout page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, coupon

I want to move where you enter the coupon at the top of the page to lower on the page (below the order summary) on the checkout page for woocommerce. Where & how can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code from form-coupon.php in the checkout folder in case it's helpful:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

if ( ! wc_coupons_enabled() ) {
return;
}

if ( ! WC()->cart->applied_coupons ) {
    $info_message = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_message', __( 'Have a coupon?', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <a href="#" class="showcoupon">' . __( 'Click here to enter your code', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' );
wc_print_notice( $info_message, 'notice' );
}
?>

<form class="checkout_coupon" method="post" style="display:none">

    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
        <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" id="coupon_code" value="" /> 
</p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-last">
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply Coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

I added the code as suggested below, which worked, but it shifted the last line on the page down, so it doesn't quite look right. Here is a picture of it (Terms and conditions and the Place Order Button.

[image: Terms and conditions are shifted down]

Comment: [Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)… Have you solve your problem with this?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec No I wasn't able to. I'm familiar with overriding templates, but I am not sure which template controls where the location of the coupon is. There is a form-coupon.php in my child theme-woocommerce-checkout folder. I have added the code from that file above in case it's helpful. Ideally, I'd like to set it so the coupon code is always entering area is always showing & have it located right below the order summary.

Comment: Finally is not really possible technically to move coupon stuff  like you wanted it… see my explanations. **But you can easily change** some things that you don't want… See my las update. And i have a little enhancement for you.

Comment: I just responded below to your comment. I thought you had sent me a message somewhere, but I don't see how to look at that, so I just wanted to say thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATED***

**NOT POSSIBLE TO MOVE COUPON FORM INSIDE CHECKOUT FORM**

Finally, it **is not possible** to insert the coupon field with his "apply" button just after your **Order Summary** title, because it is an individual form with his own submit button that you are inserting inside another form with another submit button (Place Order).

---

**WHAT YOU CAN DO AS PART OF YOUR QUESTION**:

**Keep visible *only* coupon field and button "apply" / Remove Coupon message with link:**

For that purpose (if not done yet) you will have to copy the woocommerce plugin `templates` folder inside your active child theme or theme folder and rename it `woocommerce` *([Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/))*. Don't be afraid, it's easy… Now you can customize any template.

With that `woocommerce` folder (located in your active theme) go inside subfolder `checkout` and open/edit `form-coupon.php` file.

**1) Remove or comment** ( /* … */ ):

```
if ( ! WC()->cart->applied_coupons ) {
    $info_message = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_message', __( 'Have a coupon?', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <a href="#" class="showcoupon">' . __( 'Click here to enter your code', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' );
    wc_print_notice( $info_message, 'notice' );
}
```

**2) Remove**  `style="display:none"` **from**  `<form class="checkout_coupon" method="post" style="display:none">`.

So you will stay only with: `<form class="checkout_coupon" method="post">`

---

**FINE TUNING VERTICAL SPACE:**

Adding some vertical space around "If you'd like to change your subscription, go back to Plans.":

In style.css file of your active child theme or theme, add:

```css
.woocommerce-checkout .return-to-cart {
    padding: 12px 0 24px !important;
}
```

*(END OF UPDATE)*

---

It's on *template **checkout/form-checkout.php*** (at the beginning), you have a hook `woocommerce_before_checkout_form` which display the coupon field and button:

**code to move** (on line 20) cut this code on form-checkout.php template:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', $checkout );
```

Pasting location (on line 56) just after; inside de php tags:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review' ); ?>
```

Like this (before closing `?>` php tags):

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review' );
echo '<div class="coupon-block">';
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', $checkout );
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Info: *There is no `order summary` in this template*

Comment: Wow, yes that worked!! I From what I can tell, the wc_print_notices(); didn't make any difference so I left it out. Do you happen to know how I can get rid of the grey box & the text where it says "Have a coupon? Click here to enter your code"? If possible, I would just like to have the box where you enter the coupon code & the Apply coupon button. Thank you!!!

Comment: hmm that additional code seemed to not have worked. Should I try something else?

Comment: I actually just noticed that the code from earlier (to move the coupon down on the page) caused the last line on the page to shift down as well. Do you know how I might be able to fix that? I will try to add a screenshot of the issue to the question

Comment: yes, the issue is on sprinly.com/checkout. You probably need to add something to the cart to see the issue. You can add something to the cart by going to sprinly.com/subscription-plans, then clicking "Sign Up" for any of the products, then going to sprinly.com/checkout

Comment: thanks so much for trying to help me with this issue & I'm sorry for not replying sooner. I tried your new suggestion, but the coupon input at the top displays for a split second and then disappears. I think I will try to not make any modifications to this page for now. When I moved the coupon input section lower on the page, it prevented me from checking out, so I don't want to make any changes for a little while since customers are currently using the page to checkout. Thank  you very much for your help regardless. I may revisit all of this later when I can.